# Compare file name in a dataframe to file present in a directory and then fetch row value of a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which captures 2 columns - id and corresponding filename.

I want to run a loop and compare if the filename in this dataframe is present in a specific directory. If it is present then I want to fetch the id and filename.

I am trying the following code -

```
x = df[["id", "filename_dir"]]
directory = 'C:/users/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename in x["filename_dir"]:
       id_1 = x["id"]
       print(id_1)
```

However, this is giving me complete list of ids and not the one corresponding to the filename present in the directory. I am new to python so apologies for this basic query.

Answer (score 1):

```
id = x["id"]
```

will instantiate "id" with the whole columns of x.id, so the print statement will print the whole column everytime it finds a matching file.

try

```
id = x.id[x.filename == filename]
```